# How to set path variables on osx el capitan?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, osx-elcapitan, path-variables

I've not had success setting up an environment variable on El Capitan. Nothing to do with dock or bash shell. Trying to run a java gui which requires an environment path variable to a JDBC driver to connect to an oracle db:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e38228/inst_task.htm#BABBBHJH

I have tried methods:

- in launchd.conf:
  `setenv JDBC /Users/mac_admin/Downloads/Oracle/instantclient_12_1`

  [osx - Setting environment variables in OS X? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/588442#588442)
- in .profile:
  `export JDBC /Users/mac_admin/Downloads/Oracle/instantclient_12_1`

  [terminal - How do I set environment variables on OS X? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x/106823#106823)
- in .bash_profile:
  `export JDBC=$(/Users/mac_admin/Downloads/Oracle/instantclient_12_1)`

  [Where to Set Environment Variables in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/28/set-enviornment-variables-mac-os-x/)

In each case, the `export` command at Terminal does not show the new variable.

What is correct method for El Capitan?

Is "JDBC" an acceptable name for the variable? Or am I supposed to label it `PATH`? I notice the `export` command already lists a `PATH` item, and I am afraid to overwrite it:

```
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands"
```

Is `/Users/mac_admin/Downloads/Oracle/instantclient_12_1` an acceptable location for the files?

thx

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to get some JDBC binary thing to work from a bash shell OR are you trying to get something to work from the Dock?  In OS X, the Dock is "special" in that it DOESN'T get the user's environment.  Kind-of sucks, really.

Comment: nothing to do with dock or bash shell. Trying to run a java gui which requires an environment path variable to a JDBC driver to connect to an oracle db: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e38228/inst_task.htm#BABBBHJH

Answer (score 0):

It kind-of matters where you want to use this.  If you are just trying to get some binary utility to run from Terminal shells you launch add an export into ~/.bash_profile and you are good to go:  `export JDBC='Robert was here'`

```
tcc-rkuhar:scouting robert.kuhar$ source ~/.bash_profile
tcc-rkuhar:scouting robert.kuhar$ echo $JDBC
Robert was here
```

You need the equals sign to get the environment variable set.  Assuming that the value you've put in the export JDBC is a directly that has the binaries you want to execute.  The line in your ~/.bash_profile is probably...

```
export JDBC=/Users/mac_admin/Downloads/Oracle/instantclient_12_1
PATH="${PATH}:$JDBC"
```

You'll know this worked if you

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:...blah...blah...blah::/Users/mac_admin/Downloads/Oracle/instantclient_12_1
```

Comment: not trying to run something from terminal shells. Trying to run a java gui which requires an environment path variable to a JDBC driver to connect to an oracle db: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e38228/inst_task.htm#BABBBHJH

Comment: @johnywhy so this answer should work.  Just note that the equals sign is required to get the value into the environment variable.  If the value of JDBC isn't to some directory containing executable binaries,, you don't need the whole ```PATH="${PATH}:$JDBC"``` thing

Comment: unclear. is this the solution? do i just run this at a command line? `export JDBC='Robert was here'`?

Comment: @johnywhy I really don't know that the oracle tool is doing with that environment variable, but, yes, the ```export JDBC='something_meaningful_to_oracle'``` will set an environment variable called JDBC and make it available to processes started through this shell.  What oracle wants that value to be, I don't know.

Comment: Hi @BobKuhar, thx for reply. "available to processes started through this shell" --the lifetime of the variable is only the lifetime of the terminal session, with your method? Need a permanent environment variable.

Comment: @johnywhy there is no such thing as a "permanent environment variable".   An environment is an environment.   You need to know what environment(s) you want your crap to run in.  If you can't figure out what environment you need this in, I can't help you.

Comment: i may misunderstand Mac. In Windows, you can create permanent environment variables, that last beyond the lifetime of a console window. Is that not possible in Mac? Your answer appears to be 2 different answers... or something -- can you clarify?